# flask dynamic host path

Tags: flask

I have following simple flask

**templates/fileform.html**

```
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <form action="/getSignature" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
                  <input type="submit" value="Get Signature"/>
          </form>
      </body>
  </html>
```

**templates/result.html**

```
  <html>
  <body>
      <p>Signature for file : {{ variable }}</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**app.py**

```
  import os
  from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect
  import rsa
  from binascii import hexlify
  import pickle

  SIGNING_KEY = os.getenv('SIGNING_KEY')

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route("/")
  def fileFrontPage():
      return render_template('fileform.html')

  def _sign_file(private_key_file, filename):
      print("Loading private signing key")
      with open(private_key_file,'r') as fh:
          privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(fh.read(), 'PEM')
      print("Signing file")
      with open(filename,'rb') as fh:
          signature = rsa.sign(fh, privkey, "SHA-1")
      signature = hexlify(bytearray(signature)) #Send as byte array
      return signature

  @app.route("/getSignature", methods=['POST'])
  def handleFileUpload():
      if 'photo' in request.files:
          photo = request.files['photo']
          if photo.filename != '':
              filepath = os.path.join('/flask/files', photo.filename)
              photo.save(filepath)
              signature = _sign_file(SIGNING_KEY, filepath)
              os.remove(filepath)
      return render_template('result.html', variable=signature)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This works fine on local host. But I am serving it at `domain.com/signature` via `Nginx`. When I click Get Signature it goes to `domain.com/getSignature` and shows

```
405 Method Not Allowed
Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
Method: POST
ResourceType: OBJECT
RequestId: CAB22446BEAE3B3F
HostId: cYGbt4sjHpFfrp6iBXvuYx4qzk7dkT4BqpNNJYFbeMjz34kYLtnr/RTxp8CsqvEoHTx/fVQmWsE=
```

it need to go to **domain.com/signature/getSignature**

i tried to add `app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/signature/"` but didn't work.

How can I change the host for route("/getSignature") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action should go to Nginx endpoint if Nginx is proxying it to your flask route. Based on what you said Nginx is listening on `domain.com/signature` Give this a try.

```
<form action="domain.com/signature/getSignature" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
                  <input type="submit" value="Get Signature"/>
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="/signature/getSignature" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
                  <input type="submit" value="Get Signature"/>
</form>
```